# Change auto increment starting number?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I have a table, and I want to set the `auto_increment` value to `5` instead of  `1`.  Is this possible and what query statement does this?

Comment: you can't CHANGE, only increase

Comment: @VasiliiSuricov `You can change this option with ALTER TABLE, but in that case the new value must be higher than the highest value which is present in the AUTO_INCREMENT column.` [_source_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-table/#auto_increment)
If there is no higher value than what you want to set your `auto_increment`ed column, you can also decrease the value. ([mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html))

Answer (score 615, accepted):

You can use `ALTER TABLE` to change the auto_increment initial value:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 5;
```

See the [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) for more details.

Comment: is it possible to do this dynamically with a result from a select ?

Comment: Anyone know if it is possible to do WITHOUT an ALTER?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. See my reply.

Comment: MySQL 5.6 had a bug that wouldn't allow you to decrease the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value, but it has been fixed in 5.6.16 and 5.7.4, see http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69882

Comment: Take a look at cosimo's warning about the table being rebuilt if you do this!

Comment: To clarify: Setting the initial value to 5, means that the next insert will be 5.

Comment: After mysql restart - auto_increment value is again defaulted.

Comment: After this I always google 'select auto_increment mysql' to know the current value. So the answer is `SELECT \`AUTO_INCREMENT\` FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableName';` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821532/get-current-auto-increment-value-for-any-table

Answer (score 114):

Yes, you can use the `ALTER TABLE t AUTO_INCREMENT = 42` statement. However, you need to be aware that this will cause the rebuilding of your entire table, at least with InnoDB and certain MySQL versions. **If you have an already existing dataset with millions of rows, it could take a very long time to complete**.

In my experience, it's better to do the following:

```
BEGIN WORK;
-- You may also need to add other mandatory columns and values
INSERT INTO t (id) VALUES (42);
ROLLBACK;
```

In this way, **even if you're rolling back** the transaction, MySQL will keep the auto-increment value, and the change will be applied instantly.

You can verify this by issuing a `SHOW CREATE TABLE t` statement. You should see:

```
> SHOW CREATE TABLE t \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: t
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t` (
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43 ...
```

Comment: THANKS! `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;` is also useful for this.

Comment: Brilliant idea! Nitpick: `SHOW CREATE TABLE t` will actually return `43`, i.e. next value after inserting `42`.

Comment: @cosimo, Wait, isn't this **undocumented**? Did the manual said that it should work that way? If not it may break in a different (future) mysql setup.

Comment: @Pacerier yes, you are correct. This is relying on the way MySQL works currently. It might not work like that in the future. Given MySQL history though, I would assume it will continue to work that way for a long time.

Comment: @cosimo, Hopefully they would document it so that reliable code could actually use this good hack. As of now, code which wants to be reliable can't use this.

Comment: Personally I use this as alternative only when I need to do it manually *and* I have a very large table at hand :) I wouldn't put this into some code/library.

Comment: In 5.6, at least, the ALTER only to change the auto-increment does not seem to require a rebuild.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is now documented: `In MySQL 8.0 and later, if you modify an AUTO_INCREMENT column value to a value larger than the current maximum auto-increment value, the new value is persisted, and subsequent INSERT operations allocate auto-increment values starting from the new, larger value`. From: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Answer (score 16):

### How to auto increment by one, starting at 10 in MySQL:

```
create table foobar(
  id             INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  moobar         VARCHAR(500)
); 
ALTER TABLE foobar AUTO_INCREMENT=10;

INSERT INTO foobar(moobar) values ("abc");
INSERT INTO foobar(moobar) values ("def");
INSERT INTO foobar(moobar) values ("xyz");

select * from foobar;

'10', 'abc'
'11', 'def'
'12', 'xyz'
```

This auto increments the id column by one starting at 10.

### Auto increment in MySQL by 5, starting at 10:

```
drop table foobar
create table foobar(
  id             INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  moobar         VARCHAR(500)
); 
SET @@auto_increment_increment=5;
ALTER TABLE foobar AUTO_INCREMENT=10;

INSERT INTO foobar(moobar) values ("abc");
INSERT INTO foobar(moobar) values ("def");
INSERT INTO foobar(moobar) values ("xyz");

select * from foobar;
'11', 'abc'
'16', 'def'
'21', 'xyz'
```

This auto increments the id column by 5 each time, starting at 10.

Answer (score 8):

You can also do it using phpmyadmin. Just select the table than go to actions. And change the Auto increment below table options. Don't forget to click on start
[image: Auto increment in phpmyadmin]

Comment: The menu item is now called *Operations*.

Comment: But you should understand that phpmyadmin will execute ALTER TABLE

Answer (score 6):

Procedure to auto fix AUTO_INCREMENT value of table

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS update_auto_increment;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE update_auto_increment (_table VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
    DECLARE _max_stmt VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE _stmt VARCHAR(1024);    
    SET @inc := 0;

    SET @MAX_SQL := CONCAT('SELECT IFNULL(MAX(`id`), 0) + 1 INTO @inc FROM ', _table);
    PREPARE _max_stmt FROM @MAX_SQL;
    EXECUTE _max_stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE _max_stmt;

    SET @SQL := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', _table, ' AUTO_INCREMENT =  ', @inc);
    PREPARE _stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE _stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE _stmt;
END//
DELIMITER ;

CALL update_auto_increment('your_table_name')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need this procedure for variable fieldnames instead of `id` this might be helpful:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS update_auto_increment;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE update_auto_increment (_table VARCHAR(128), _fieldname VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN
    DECLARE _max_stmt VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE _stmt VARCHAR(1024);    
    SET @inc := 0;

    SET @MAX_SQL := CONCAT('SELECT IFNULL(MAX(',_fieldname,'), 0) + 1 INTO @inc FROM ', _table);
    PREPARE _max_stmt FROM @MAX_SQL;
    EXECUTE _max_stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE _max_stmt;

    SET @SQL := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', _table, ' AUTO_INCREMENT =  ', @inc);
    PREPARE _stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE _stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE _stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL update_auto_increment('your_table_name', 'autoincrement_fieldname');
```

Answer (score 0):

**My case.**

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fix_id;
CREATE PROCEDURE fix_id()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE tableName VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'db'; -- database_name
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO tableName;
        SELECT tableName AS '** DEBUG:';

        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        SET @COUNT = 0;
        SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE ', tableName, ' SET id = @COUNT:=@COUNT+1;');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        SET @T = NULL;
        SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT MAX(id) INTO @T FROM ', tableName, ';');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', tableName, ' AUTO_INCREMENT = ', IFNULL(@T, 0) + 1);
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    END LOOP read_loop;

    CLOSE cur;
END;
//

DELIMITER ;

-- CALL fix_id()
```

Answer (score -3):

just export the table with data ..
then copy its sql like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
  `emp_badgenumber` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_fullname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `emp_father_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `emp_mobile` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_cnic` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `emp_is_deleted` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `emp_registration_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `emp_overtime_allowed` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_badgenumber`),
  UNIQUE KEY `bagdenumber` (`emp_badgenumber`),
  KEY `emp_badgenumber` (`emp_badgenumber`),
  KEY `emp_badgenumber_2` (`emp_badgenumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=111121326 ;
```

now change auto increment value and execute sql.