# Changing the current count of an Auto Increment value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Currently every time I add an entry to my database, the auto increment value increments by 1, as it should. However, it is only at a count of 47. So, if I add a new entry, it will be 48, and then another it will be 49 etc.

I want to change what the current Auto Increment counter is at. I.e. I want to change it from 47 to say, 10000, so that the next value entered, will be 10001. How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change auto increment starting number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970597/change-auto-increment-starting-number)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can use [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) to set the value of an AUTO_INCREMENT column ; quoting that page :

> To change the value of the
> `AUTO_INCREMENT`  counter to be used for
> new rows, do this:

```
ALTER TABLE t2 AUTO_INCREMENT = value;
```

There is also a note saying that :

> You cannot reset the counter to a
> value less than or equal to any that
> have already been used.
>
> For MyISAM, if
> the value is less than or equal to the
> maximum value currently in the
> `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, the value is
> reset to the current maximum plus one.
>
> For InnoDB, if the value is less than
> the current maximum value in the
> column, no error occurs and the
> current sequence value is not changed.

Comment: I'd like to mention that you can only change `AUTO_INCREMENT` to a concrete number. Expressions are not allowed. I tried to "skip" some values by `ALTER TABLE t2 AUTO_INCREMENT = <the_current_value> + value` and `ALTER TABLE t2 AUTO_INCREMENT = AUTO_INCREMENT + value` but both resulted in an error which seemed a little bit strange. MySQL version `5.6.33`

Answer (score 18):

See manual for [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) - this should do it:

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] AUTO_INCREMENT = [number]
```

Answer (score 11):

you can get that done by executing the following statement

```
ALTER TABLE t2 AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

So next Auto Increment key will start from the 10001.

I hope this will solve the problem

Comment: Why were you repeating an already given answer and did you include a spam link? Please don't do that. Greeting isn't needed (your name already appears under the post) and spamming also not (just put it in your user profile).

Comment: It's the only answer that explains, that setting a value of 10000 will begin inserting with ID of 10001.

Comment: Actually, the [Value] is the next number to be used ... NOT the previous value.  Therefore the NEXT Auto increment will be 10000 ... NOT 10001.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set it with the table creation statement as follows;

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
     id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     ...
     PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)AUTO_INCREMENT=10000;
```

Hope it helps someone.