# Changing auto-increment ID in MySQL table of Rails application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have read this:
[Changing the current count of an Auto Increment value in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476512/changing-the-current-count-of-an-auto-increment-value-in-mysql)

The max ID in one of my tables is 1382, and I would like the next entity created to start at 5000.

I could do `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 5000`

Is there any danger of doing this in a Rails Application?

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be run on database ,on rails application we just use adapters to connect to database .I don't see anything danger doing this.