# mysql int column auto increment by 1 starting at 10000

Tags: mysql

I have an int column which is set to be auto_increment by 1, however, i cant figure out how to make the column start at the number 10000 instead of 1.

Thanks!

let me clarify I want it by 1, but to start at 10,000, so i would get 10000, 10001, 10002, 10003

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;` should work.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/970597/456712

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

Comment: let me clarify I want it by 1, but to start at 10,000, so i would get 10000, 10001, 10002, 10003

Comment: @Mike: yes, exactly what I wrote ;)

Comment: i guess when i read that to me its increase increments by 10000

Comment: @Mike: no, that's the starting value; then everytime you insert a new record passing null as id (or not using it in your query) it's incremented by one.

Answer (score 3):

If you have phpmyadmin:

Select the table you need, then go to Operations. There you have an input field called AUTO_INCREMENT. Type the number you want here and viola.

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE  `your_table` AUTO_INCREMENT=10000
```