# Delete all rows with timestamp older than x days

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I want to delete all the rows with timestamp older than 180 days from a specific table in my database.

I've tried the this:

```
DELETE FROM on_search WHERE search_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 180 DAY);
```

But that deleted all the rows and not only the rows older than 6 months.

I have a column in on_search table called search_date and contains the time when that row was created.

```
search_id   search_term    search_date 
660779      car games      1390052553
```

Comment: Can you show example data?

Comment: search_id search_term search_date
660779   car games  1390052553

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM on_search 
WHERE search_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 180 DAY))
```

Comment: the column search_date is of type int?

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks! I am sorry for asking so many questions, but is there any way to re-assign search_id with new ids starting from 1? (Deleting part of the data left the table with ids not starting from 1)

Comment: You can change the auto-increment starting number.  But be careful; you might seriously foul up your table's keying.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970597/change-auto-increment-starting-number

Comment: Is there a way we can run this command on all tables in the database?

Comment: @Farveaz it's not a command, it's a query and I suggest you create a question for that in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 68):

```
DELETE FROM on_search WHERE search_date < NOW() - INTERVAL N DAY
```

Replace N with your day count

Comment: That deleted all the rows despite the fact that there are stamps that were created today.

Comment: @Khaleal You can replace NOW() with any date you want

Comment: This works fine with datetime columns. Not with timestamp as asked.