# How to delete rows with timestamp older than 7 days

Tags: php

My timestamp format looks like this: **`2014-02-27 08:54:53`**

The table is `product_views`, and the time field is `ViewStamp`. I don't know how to DELETE rows older than 7 days.

```
$query="DELETE FROM product_views WHERE ViewStamp< ?";
```

Thanks for the help. I am still a beginner so if I did not provide enough info please let me know and I will edit.

edit: Using MySQL

Comment: What is your database ? (MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete all rows with timestamp older than x days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206361/delete-all-rows-with-timestamp-older-than-x-days)

Comment: MySQL is what I am using.

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE FROM product_views WHERE ViewStamp < DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL 7 DAYS)`

If you just want from "now" instead of passing a timestamp as a parameter, you can replace the `?` with the SQL function `NOW()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like:

```
DELETE FROM product_views WHERE ViewStamp < (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "DELETE FROM product_views WHERE ViewStamp < now() - interval 7 day";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the date_add function you can do this. Assuming that you are using MySQL

```
DELETE FROM product_views WHERE ViewStamp < DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -7 DAY)
```