# Truncate table with date time older than n days

Tags: mysql, truncate

I want to `truncate` some records from a table with date time clause.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21206561/8919244) link have a solution, but it's not working for me.

`TRUNCATE TABLE 'meter_to_sim_mapping' WHERE 'meter_to_sim_mapping'.'mapped_at' <=`

In above where clause I want to add the date time value. The value is `2018-04-02 16:03:52`. The query should delete all the records prior to this date.

How can I truncate the table with date-time?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use TRUNCATE, use DELETE

Comment: TRUNCATE TABLE empties a table completely https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DELETE`

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE DATE_COLUMN < NOW() - INTERVAL N DAY
```

or

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE CAST(DATE_COLUMN AS DATE) < STR_TO_DATE('1-01-2012', '%d-%m-%Y')  - INTERVAL N DAY
```

In place of `NOW()` You can use your datetime value

```
STR_TO_DATE('12-01-2014 00:00:00','%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4607a6/1

Comment: I don't want to use `NOW()`. I want to give a date and then subtract the days from it

Comment: here's my query 

`DELETE FROM `meter_to_sim_mapping` WHERE CAST(`meter_to_sim_mapping`.`mapped_at` AS DATE) < STR_TO_DATE('2018-04-02', '%d-%m-%Y')  - INTERVAL 2 DAY`

Comment: and it's giving me 

`0 Rows affected`
`Warning Code : 1411
Incorrect datetime value: '2018-04-02' for function str_to_date`

Comment: again 0 rows affected

Answer (score 1):

Below example may work for you:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE DATE_COLUMN = DATE_SUB("2018-04-02 16:03:52", INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```

You can change it accordingly as per your requirement.

**Reference:** [MySQL DATE_SUB() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp)