# MYSQL - Delete Rows where inputs older then x days for each idnummber

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i have a problem i cannot find a way to solve my problem:

[image]

I want to delete for each accountNumber older Data then X Days how is this possible ?

Best regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete all rows with timestamp older than x days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21206361/delete-all-rows-with-timestamp-older-than-x-days)

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
delete t from t
    where date < curdate() - interval X day;
```

If not, please provide more information *in your question*.

Comment: no, i need to delete for every accountnumber the old data , maybe it works instad of using the date a limit of 70