# Adding 2000 autocomplete field records to an existing mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, autocomplete

I have a table named `users`

**fields:**

```
ID INT
First_name VARCHAR
Second_name VARCHAR
National_ID INT
```

The ID field is an AUTO_INCREMENT.

I need to AUTO_INCREMENT the first 2000 users with just the ID and the other fields remain blank,so that the new users will start at 2001.

Kindly assist.

Comment: You can set AUTOINCREMENT property to 2000.

Comment: ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 2001

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change auto increment starting number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970597/change-auto-increment-starting-number)

Comment: DO NOT USE AUTO_INCREMENT FOR THIS!!! Despite its name, that's not what it's for!

Comment: setting the start value of AUTO_INCREMENT to 2001, solves half the problem, now how do i populate the first 2000 fields with just the ID field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called auto increment, your ID column must be set to auto increment.

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=2001;
```

**Update**

If you wish to actually create those rows (not just set the auto increment value) you can use PHP for this:

```
for($i=1; $i<=2000; $i++)
{
    $query = 'INSERT INTO users (id) VALUES ('.$i.')';
    //execute this query using your desired PDO or sql extension
}
```