# How to find all the AUTO_INCREMENT table?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I need to find all the tables in a MySQL database schema that have AUTO_INCREMENT columns.

I need to be able to set all these tables to a large AUTO_INCREMENT value so as not to overlap the base data that will be added to (million?).

I know that it is a bad idea, but I do not expect the base data to exceed 1000 items per table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
use information_schema;
select table_name 
from tables 
where auto_increment is not null and table_schema=...;
```

You can then set the auto-increment value as per [Change auto increment starting number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970597/change-auto-increment-starting-number)

Or, in a single shot (assuming Unix shell):

```
mysql information_schema -e 
'select concat ("ALTER TABLE ",table_name," AUTO_INCREMENT=1000000") `-- sql` 
from tables 
where auto_increment is not null and table_schema="your-schema";
'|mysql your-schema
```

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer...  [this will find all the columns with auto_increment](http://blog.geekslikeshinythings.com/2014/11/find-all-autoincrement-tables.html)

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE 
    `EXTRA` = 'auto_increment' AND 
    `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'foochoo'
```

Comment: This is useful to find all auto_increment columns in all databases and tables removing the last part " AND TABLE_SCHEMA...."

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used, all executable from within mysql cli.

```
use information_schema;
SELECT concat ("ALTER TABLE `",table_name,"` AUTO_INCREMENT=",IF(DATA_TYPE='smallint',15000,IF(DATA_TYPE='tinyint',64,IF(DATA_TYPE='mediumint',4000000,IF(DATA_TYPE='int',1000000000,99999999999999)))),";")
FROM `COLUMNS` WHERE extra LIKE '%auto_increment%' and table_schema='myschema'
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/auto.sql';
use izon;
source /tmp/auto.sql;
```

this allowed for a specific size per data_type so i could increase the length to "half way".