# Automatically set auto_increment for ALL tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Given a database with hundreds or thousands of tables:

Considering that all tables were empty. Is there a way to automatically set `auto_increment` to 1 for all tables?

Comment: `auto_increment`  can **only be unique** on a given table.

Comment: You'd need to loop through all the tables (not possible to do this en masse directly in MySQL, AFAIK), and use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970597/change-auto-increment-starting-number

Comment: You can do this by running a command in the shell. You can try something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912813/truncate-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-in-one-command . What's more, if all the tables are really empty, you can just truncate all them as the answer from the link without any changing the command.

Comment: @AD7six debugging and testing purposes

Answer (score 1):

Could try give it a go in PHP? Would have to know all of the table names.

```
$tableName = array('somename', 'someOtherName', ...);

foreach ($tableName as $key) {
//Do the query
ALTER TABLE $key MODIFY COLUMN id INT auto_increment
}
```

Pseudo code.. but you get the idea right?

Answer (score 1):

> a database with hundreds or thousands of tables

That's likely to be a big mistake.

To do the task, write a Stored Procedure that creates a Cursor walking through information_schema.TABLES and building the SQL needed for each table.  Then prepare() and execute() it.

If the SQL is not allowed in a Stored Procedure, then simply SELECT the SQL to show it.  Then manually copy and past it into the mysql commandline tool.