# dynamically change the auto-increment in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, auto-increment

I have a form that adds some data to a table.and i have a php file that prints out the data.in this page in each row a link is printed that when you click on it you will proceed to a page that deletes that single row.
this page is called delete.php
but there is a problem:when a single row is deleted , if i add another row , the auto-increment will be printed wrong!
fow example if you delete row 7 and there are 13 rows printed,when you add another row the printed auto-increment column will be something like this:
1,2,...,12,14

here's the code of delete.php:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);  
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
 else {
    echo "" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

$id=$_GET['id'];


$sql = "DELETE FROM qolak WHERE id='$id'";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "";
    for($i=$id+1;$i<=1000;$i++){
    $j=$i-1;
    $sql = "UPDATE qolak SET id='$j' WHERE id='$i'";
   // 

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
 }
    }
$rownum=$_GET['rownum'];
$rownum+=1;
$ssql = "ALTER TABLE qolak AUTO_INCREMENT ='$rownum'";


    if (mysqli_query($conn, $ssql)) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "" . mysqli_error($conn);

}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

here is my problem:

```
$ssql = "ALTER TABLE qolak AUTO_INCREMENT ='$rownum'";
```

this query wont dynamically change the auto-increment
please help!!!

Comment: What you're a trying to do is **USELESS**

Comment: I second @u_mulder statement, this is a useless step. plus, if `$rownum` is to be `AUTO_INCREMENT` why are you quoting it as a string `...AUTO_INCREMENT ='$rownum'`? see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970597/change-auto-increment-starting-number

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Auto Increment after delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214141/mysql-auto-increment-after-delete)

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. Never pass user input direct to a query. `$id=$_GET['id']; $sql = "DELETE FROM qolak WHERE id='$id'";` Use prepared statements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chosen approach doesn't meet the basic problem:

You must distinguish between your auto-increment as an ID and your Output as a kind of human readable numbering. Separate this, as auto-increment will never be continuous and that's by design!

*You should never ever try to manually change auto-increment values at all. Period.*

If you want to have some continuous row numbering, add an extra column on your html (NOT in the database as there are no "row numbers" in there!)

Deleting the row #7 with `ID = 13` will then cause row #8 to become the new 7 and so on.