# How to give Jpa @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) a start value instead of 0

Tags: mysql, jpa

> I have an entity that is supposed to get an id from the database automatically. I use MySQL so I would expect annotating that @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)  When i run the project i will import hardcoded master data needed for my application, but when i add a new data to same table using jpa it starts with id 0 thus saying id already exist.
>    I have to make jpa start auto increment from the last id i have added . Is this possible

Comment: Ensure the imported data uses auto-increment or change the value after the import  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970597/change-auto-increment-starting-number

Comment: I think jpa will not care for mysql it has its own way to create id?? i am using @generated value annotation

Comment: Well if you posted the relevant info that would be clearer. With MySql I would normally use an auto-increment column managed by the database.

Comment: Is there a way to make jpa do this??

Comment: "make jpa do this" ? That is why you have strategy on the `@GeneratedValue` annotation. You selected "AUTO" which leaves it for the JPA provider to do what it wants. Just select "IDENTITY" strategy and you should get MySQL AUTOINCREMENT

Comment: Assuming your column actually has AUTO_INCREMENT defined you can, of course, do like this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485668/how-to-set-initial-value-and-auto-increment-in-mysql

Comment: Sorry if i am wrong i have many tables so it will be difficult to write auto increment query for all,instead if i have @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO   &  something like init value=1000) my problem solved

Comment: You can't using JPA (without changing your strategy). I already said that AUTO means you leave it to the implementation, so you've thrown away control at that point. You can only control init value when using SEQUENCE or TABLE

Answer (score 1):

Use the `GenerationType.TABLE` approach here in order to feed the data based on what value already present in your database.

Comment: Is there any other way?? If i change @generated value it will affect whole application

Comment: I don't think any other way left here, try to query OPENJPA_SEQUENCE_TABLE in your database and update the initial value to the one which you want.

Answer (score 0):

We can use **@SequenceGenerator** to specify the start sequence.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_data")
@SequenceGenerator(name="employee_id_seq", initialValue=5, allocationSize=100)
public class EmployeeDO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="employee_id_seq")
    private Long id;
```

Comment: as long as the database being used supports SEQUENCEs (which MySQL doesn't AFAIK).