# MySQL auto-increment reset to 1 by itself

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

what can trigger an auto-increment reset on mysql table other than :

- restart mysql service
- truncate table

can any one help me understand this behavior ?

Comment: Did the data in the table disappear?

Comment: This would https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970597/change-auto-increment-starting-number

Comment: restart mysql service will not trigger a auto-increment reset on a table(s)

Comment: What storage engine are you using (InnoDB, MyISAM, other)? Can you provide more details of your case?.

Comment: i use an InnoDB engine , in fact i have a table which i purge every night and normally the auto-increment value is preserved but i noticed that from time to time its happen that  auto-increment value is reset to 1 . 
ps : for the purge i use a delete query not a trucate

Comment: @Mouad.bll Did you solve this problem? I run into a familiar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512290/auto-increment-has-been-reset-back-to-1-automatically