# Can't get table column to auto increment from preset value

Tags: mysql

I want to make a column in my table auto-increment starting from the value 1001, not 1, but it's giving me an error when I try to set `AUTO_INCREMENT = 1001`.

I created my column like this: `ALTER TABLE users ADD id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ADD INDEX (id);`

And then I tried adding auto-increment from 1001 like this: `ALTER TABLE users COLUMN id AUTO_INCREMENT=1001;`.

But it gave me the error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLUMN id AUTO_INCREMENT=1001' at line 1`. And the value stayed at 1.

EDIT: I tried only `ALTER TABLE clients AUTO_INCREMENT=1001`. While it doesn't give me any error, the value of the column stays 1.

EDIT 2: It worked now after I deleted the rows and added them again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970597/change-auto-increment-starting-number

Comment: changing the auto increment will not update your already inserted rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1001;`

Comment: This doesn't give me any error but the value stays at 1. It doesn't change it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this out 
mysql> ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1001;

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to mention the column name, just add auto increment you will get that.

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=1001
```