# mysql middle row deleted and fix primary key with arranging order

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table with id that is primary key activated with 20 data inserted .  and i have deleted row 15,16,17 and how can i arrange increasing order from 1 to 17

```
   CREATE TABLE `cart` (
    `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
    `productname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `productquantity` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `productsize` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `productprice` varchar(255) NOT NULL
```

)

Comment: What is your MySQL version ?

Comment: You need to change the value of the auto_increment for your column.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970597/change-auto-increment-starting-number

Comment: Do not change the value of the primary keys.  There is no need to do this (other than esthetics).  Primary keys are used for other things -- such as foreign key relationships -- and changing them is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

- Determine row_number for each row, in an increasing order of `id`, starting from 1 in a Derived Table.
- Join this Derived table with your main table, and update the `id` value to be equal to row_number. This will reset all the `id` values to start from 1 (with no gaps).

Try (works for all MySQL versions):

```
UPDATE your_table AS t1 
JOIN  
(
  SELECT @row_no := @row_no + 1 AS row_num, 
         id  
  FROM your_table
  JOIN (SELECT @row_no := 0) AS init 
  ORDER BY id 
) AS dt ON dt.id = t1.id  
SET t1.id = dt.row_num;
```

### [DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/21tmeeQVj9GPNAYQGCkHzo/0)